# How to add image to blog in summary of orchard cms

Tags: orchardcms

I want to add image to the summary of blogs in Orchard CMS. How do I add it to the summary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Placement.info](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info/). In your theme's placement.info add something like this:

```xml
<Match ContentType="Blog">
    <Match DisplayType="Summary">
        <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker="Content:1" />
        <!-- Or: <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker_Summary="Content:1" /> -->
    </Match>
</Match>
```

See [this source code](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.MediaLibrary/Placement.info#L101) to see which shapes are available for this.

**Note:** I am assuming here that you are using the media library picker field to attach an image to your blog. If you use something else, you should use that shape.

Comment: I want to change the blog layout.I want to order this in title then publish date,picture and then description.but I don't know how to do this.can you help me plaese?